# Is there a single snmp command to get list of snmp enabled devices in some ip address range

Tags: snmp, oid

In my network, I want to scan for snmp enabled devices. So is there any single line snmp command, to get list of snmp enabled devices in specific range of IP Address like 172.26.1.1 to 172.26.1.255.

I found a link which says it is possible but it does not mention the command.

https://support.panorama9.com/hc/en-us/articles/203568188-Test-if-SNMP-devices-are-responding-correctly-to-SNMP-queries

Is there any generic OID to achieve this or single snmp command ?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can try to use the subnet broadcast address but from the SNMP FAQ most devices have this turned off. So this probably won't work very well.

http://www.snmp.com/FAQs/snmp-faq-part2.txt

> 2.60.12
>   SUBJECT: How should an agent respond to a broadcast request?
>
> When an SNMP request is sent with a broadcast address, Who is
>   supposed to respond? Ideally every host in the subnet should respond.
>   But I notice that it doesn't happen. What is the expected behaviour when
>   a directed broadcast is done?
>
> Depending on how the agent is written, it may respond, or
>   just drop the message. Many agents just drop the message.
>   I believe that is what the SNMP agent in cisco product do.

Another alternative is to try to use nmap to scan for hosts that respond to SNMP as well as attempt to see what community strings they respond to.

https://www.vanstechelman.eu/networking/scanning_for_snmp_services_with_default_community_strings

also

https://nmap.org/nsedoc/scripts/snmp-brute.html